# Writing a Shell - use system() or exec() to run commands?

Tags: c++, shell, exec, fork

I heard of two ways of writing our own shell. First way includes steps:

1- input commands in a while loop
2- inside loop use fork() (to make a process)for each command and then use exec() system call to execute that command.

Second way is:

1- input commands in a while loop
2- inside loop use fork() (to make a process)for each command and then use system() system call to execute that command.

I wanted to know that which one of these is preferable to use.
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system(3)` call invokes `/bin/sh` to run the command.

If you consider calling the system shell a legitimate way of "implementing" your own shell, then you can also get rid of the while loop and just have a `myshell.c` containing

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
  execve("/bin/sh", argv, environ);
}
```